# android: dlopen failed to load not 32 bit

Tags: android, react-native, .so

There's giving me following error in my demo app:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.example.android.pos_api_android_demo, PID: 9359
                                                                                        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.example.android.pos_api_android_demo-13/libPosAPI.so" not 32-bit: 2
                                                                                            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
                                                                                            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                                            at com.vatps.android.PosAPI.<clinit>(PosAPI.java:35)
                                                                                            at com.example.android.pos_api_android_demo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4867)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19722)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*Yes , libPosAPI.so file is 64 bit. There are solution like this. [https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4186][1]*

[1]: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4186 But this is for linux user. I'm using Windows. and old topic is all about error:32 bit instead 64.

My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.pos_api_android_demo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk file }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're using-  it matters what the target OS is.  And Android is a Linux based OS.  That link should be applicable.

Comment: There says Android development is only supported on Linux.

Comment: linux is a free OS.  If you need to, download a VM and install linux on it, build the .so there, and transfer it to Windows.  Its unlikely to be necessary though, cross-compiling is probably good enough.

Comment: if i don't find answer i will do it.